# Load forms without reloading forms services each time

Tags: caching, applet, jvm, oracle-apex, oracleforms

we are migrating our **Oracle Forms 10g** application to **APEX 4.1**.

We need to include some Forms into APEX.

We have a PL/SQL function `call_form` (see below), called from an APEX region, that simply writes the applet to load the form, passing the form name as parameter.

It works, but **it always reload Forms services** and it takes arround **10s** each time, the Oracle Application Server Forms Services logo appears each time :

[image]

It is really a pain for users...

I thought it was because it was reloading jar files each time, so I have tried to use **cache options** when writting the applet (*cache_option*, *cache_archive*, ...) to cache the files in the **JVM**, without success.

I don't get the **applet security warning** each time, in the **java cache viewer** I can see the 4 jar files *frmall.jar*, *frmwebutil.jar*, *FDialogPJC.jar* and *jacob.jar*.

Here is the **content of the Java console** when calling a form, and then reloading the page, it seems it loads **webutil** 2 times :

```
 RegisterWebUtil - Loading WebUtil Version 10.1.2.3
 proxyHost=null
 proxyPort=0
 connectMode=HTTP, native.
 Forms Applet version is : 10.1.2.3
 RegisterWebUtil - Loading WebUtil Version 10.1.2.3
 proxyHost=null
 proxyPort=0
 connectMode=HTTP, native.
 Forms Applet version is : 10.1.2.3
```

**My JVM is 1.6.0_31**.

The `call_form` procedure :

```
 procedure call_form(in_form_name in varchar2) is
 begin
   htp.p(' 
 <object classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" codebase="http://javadl-esd.sun.com/update/1.6.0/jinstall-6-windows-i586.cab" width="0" height="0" hspace="0" vspace="0">
   <param name="type" value="application/x-java-applet">
   <param name="codebase" value="http://myhost.ch/forms/java">
   <param name="code" value="oracle.forms.webutil.common.RegisterWebUtil">
   <param name="cache_option" value="Plugin">
   <param name="cache_archive" value="frmwebutil.jar,jacob.jar">
   <param name="cache_version" value="">
   <comment>
     <embed src="" pluginspage="https://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp"
       type="application/x-java-applet"
       java_codebase="http://myhost.ch/forms/java"
       java_code="oracle.forms.webutil.common.RegisterWebUtil"
       cache_option="Plugin"
       cache_archive="frmwebutil.jar,jacob.jar"
       cache_version=""
       width="0"
       height="0"
       hspace="0"
       vspace="0">
     </embed>
     <noembed>Registration applet definition</noembed>
   </comment>
 </object>

 <object classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" codebase="http://javadl-esd.sun.com/update/1.6.0/jinstall-6-windows-i586.cab" width="1015" height="745" hspace="0" vspace="0">
   <param name="type" value="application/x-java-applet">
   <param name="codebase" value="http://myhost.ch/forms/java">
   <param name="code" value="oracle.forms.engine.Main">
   <param name="cache_option" value="Plugin">
   <param name="cache_archive" value="frmall.jar,FDialogPJC.jar,frmwebutil.jar,jacob.jar">
   <param name="cache_version" value=""> 
   <param name="serverURL" value="http://myhost.ch/forms/lservlet?ifcfs=http://myhost.ch/forms/frmservlet?config=myconfig&#38;form='||in_form_name||'.fmx&#38;acceptLanguage=fr">
   <param name="networkRetries" value="0">
   <param name="serverArgs" value="escapeParams=true module='||in_form_name||'.fmx userid= sso_userid=%20 sso_formsid=%25OID_FORMSID%25 sso_subDN= sso_usrDN= debug=no host= port= buffer_records=no debug_messages=no array=no obr=no query_only=no quiet=yes render=no record= tracegroup= log= term=">
   <param name="separateFrame" value="False">
   <param name="splashScreen" value="">
   <param name="background" value="">
   <param name="lookAndFeel" value="Oracle">
   <param name="colorScheme" value="teal">
   <param name="serverApp" value="default">
   <param name="logo" value="">
   <param name="imageBase" value="DocumentBase">
   <param name="formsMessageListener" value="">
   <param name="recordFileName" value="">
   <param name="EndUserMonitoringEnabled" value="">
   <param name="EndUserMonitoringURL" value="">
   <param name="heartBeat" value="">
   <param name="WebUtilLogging" value="off">
   <param name="WebUtilLoggingDetail" value="normal">
   <param name="WebUtilErrorMode" value="Alert">
   <param name="WebUtilDispatchMonitorInterval" value="5">
   <param name="WebUtilTrustInternal" value="true">
   <param name="WebUtilMaxTransferSize" value="16384">
   <comment>
     <embed src="" pluginspage="https://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp"
       type="application/x-java-applet"
       java_codebase="http://myhost.ch/forms/java"
       java_code="oracle.forms.engine.Main"
       cache_option="Plugin"
       cache_archive="frmall.jar,FDialogPJC.jar,frmwebutil.jar,jacob.jar"
       cache_version=""
       width="1015"
       height="745"
       hspace="0"
       vspace=""
       serverURL="http://myhost.ch/forms/lservlet?ifcfs=http://myhost.ch/forms/frmservlet?config=myconfig&#38;form='||in_form_name||'.fmx&#38;acceptLanguage=fr"
       networkRetries="0"
       serverArgs="escapeParams=true module='||in_form_name||'.fmx userid= sso_userid=%20 sso_formsid=%25OID_FORMSID%25 sso_subDN= sso_usrDN= debug=no host= port= buffer_records=no debug_messages=no array=no obr=no query_only=no quiet=yes render=no record= tracegroup= log= term="
       separateFrame="False"
       splashScreen=""
       background=""
       lookAndFeel="Oracle"
       colorScheme="teal"
       serverApp="default"
       logo=""
       imageBase="DocumentBase"
       recordFileName=""
       EndUserMonitoringEnabled=""
       EndUserMonitoringURL=""
       heartBeat=""
       WebUtilLogging="off"
       WebUtilLoggingDetail="normal"
       WebUtilErrormode="Alert"
       WebUtilDispatchMonitorInterval="5"
       WebUtilTrustInternal="true"
       WebUtilMaxTransferSize="16384">
     </embed>
     <noembed>Forms applet definition</noembed>
   </comment>
 </object>
 ');
 end;
```

Have you any idea on **how I can prevent that** ? Or do you think there is a better way to include Oracle Forms into APEX ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you access the forms in your Oracle forms 10g Application?? Do you load each and every form separately the same way you are doing in APEX 4.1?? If the above statement is not true then try following the same approach that you use in Oracle forms 10g Application

Comment: To access the Forms 10g application, users just start the main page by calling the right URL http://myhost.ch/forms/frmservlet?config=myconfig&form=mainform.fmx then they can navigate into the application using the main menu, without reloading the applets. But in Apex we need to call these pages independently, without any menu to navigate into the Forms application.

Comment: Since you are doing the same thing of going to the main page with invoking individual forms in APEX you would get the FORMS services loaded again ,you can verify the same using the URL to invoke individual forms,Better way might be converting the forms to APEX application ,an example is available at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/apex32frmmigr-095892.html#t5

Comment: Yes, I know this is the problem :) I have to understand what is causing that loading time, Forms services initialization ? applet ? database connection ? ... We are already converting each Forms to Apex manually (arround 250 forms), most of them are too much complicated, and some need to be revised, so we cannot use converting tools. I am testing some things (calling a form without database connection, inline frames, etc...). I will update my post as soon as I get conclusive results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [oracle views and network traffic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812405/oracle-views-and-network-traffic)

Comment: Instead of outputting a webpage in Apex can you redirect the user?  

I've used something like this:  
    `OWA_UTIL.REDIRECT_URL  
        ('http://' || l_domain  || ':' || l_port ||  '/forms/frmservlet?config='  
         || :REQUEST  
         || '&RP2RROREPORTSERVER=' || l_report_server  
         || '&LOGINKEY='  
         || l_login_key);`  

LOGINKEY is a sort of one time key. I generate it in the code that calls this redirect and insert it into a table. The Forms authentication was changed to then look for this key and delete it.