# oracle views and network traffic

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, oracleforms

I cant really understand what this line from the [Oracle E-Business Suite Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e12897/T302934T303920.htm) means. When using views, "network traffic is minimized because all foreign keys are
denormalized on the server."

Could anyone please throw some light on when a query, associated with a view is parsed?
Is a query associated with a view is already parsed?

I cant find the answers. Please provide any oracle documentation links that would be helpful.

Comment: Where did you find this statement?

Comment: it is in oracle applications developer guide RELEASE 11i.

Comment: All the people voting to close this question are **wrong** .  It is a programming question.  Specifically it relates to application design using Oracle Forms.

Comment: Agree with APC -- the closure votes make no sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quote is talking about E-Business Suite, and specifically, how to build EBS (i.e. Forms) applications in a performant fashion.  The pertinent context is this:

> "In general, complex blocks are based on views while simple setup blocks are based on tables."

Take this scenario: we have a table with many columns, including three which are foreign keys to lookup tables.  We want to display data from this table in a Form.  To be user-friendly our Form needs to show the meanings from the lookup tables not the codes from the main table.  It is more efficient to execute a single query joining to the reference tables than to issue four queries.  Because network traffic, and other considerations.

So we should build the Form's data block on a view which joins all four tables, rather than building it just on the main table and using Post-Query triggers to issue three separate queries which retrieve the codes' descriptions.  This is especially relevant with multi-row blocks: we definitely want to avoid issuing several queries for each record returned.

Although the context for the quote is Oracle Forms, the point pertinent for most data retrieval applications.  Although I suspect these days using a ref cursor to pass a result set is a more popular solution than using views.

**tl;dr**

It is a statement about application design not database optimization